# Admob Banner ad not appearing for each fragment

Tags: android

For some reason , my banner ad is appearing for the first fragment , but fails to appear for each new fragment after that.

I call the createAdmobBanner() method from MainActivity.java in each fragment but it's not appearing

**MainActiviy.java**

```
    public void createAdmobBanner() 
    {
    adView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
    }
```

**Fragment Classes**

I call the method in each fragment

```
((MainActivity) getActivity()).createAdmobBanner();
```

**XML:**

```
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/adViewHolder"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="@dimen/ad_bottom_height"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
android:background="@color/list_background"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-xxx/xxxx"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Might be possible Ad is not loaded yet,
I believe you are not using the banner ID as you shared above i.e.
ca-app-pub-xxx/xxxx

so to check your implementation use this testing ID for banner

> ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111

you can find ads test Ids [here.](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/test-ads)

If you still find the issue follow the instructions [here](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/banner) and check if you are missing any thing.

Hopefully this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void createAdmobBanner() {
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
Fragment currentFragment = 
fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.frame_container);

if (currentFragment != null && currentFragment.getView() != null) {
adView = currentFragment.getView().findViewById(R.id.adView);
if (adView != null) {
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
adView.loadAd(adRequest);
}
}
}
```

Comment: Use the same banner for all fragments, it'll give more revenue and performance

Answer (score 0):

If you have a single `Activity` with multiple `Fragment`s then you need to initialize the ads in the `Activity` only and the same banner will appear everywhere, no need to call it everytime.